# Compare two dates in rules yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to compare 2 dates in rules.
When I enter a date and time in `start_date` and `end_date`, I get the error message "End must be greater than or equal to Start"
The start_date and end_date are datetime fields.
I'm looking for a solution.

```
return [
        ['end_date', 'date', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s', 'skipOnEmpty' => false],
        ['start_date', 'date', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s', 'skipOnEmpty' => false],
        ['end_date', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'start_date', 'operator' => '>='],
    ];
```

Comment: Is that a typo in your question then, because the operator there is >, not >=

Comment: No typo, I'm comparing date and time. And the to end_date must be higher.

Comment: Well then I don't understand your problem, if you enter the same date for start and end dates, as you said in your question, then your validation is working correctly

Comment: Ok, I can see that, so what dates are you entering, and what, precisely, is the problem? Are your dates and times the same, or not? What are you expecting to happen that isn't? Sorry for all the questions, I'm really trying to understand what the problem is!

Comment: start_date = 12-12-2015  10:15 and the end_date = 12-12-2015  11:15 this gives the error as above.

Comment: your code is seem like correct for your error.Actually what you want.I think it is giving you correct answer.

Comment: Ok, so the dates you have given are not correct for the format you have asked Yii to validate against. The correct format for the dates should be 2015-12-12 10:15 and 2015-12-12 11:15. Also, you have specified that there should be seconds in the date/time format, but you haven't inputted them to the field. Can you amend your question to include the date information, and retry with correct formats?

Comment: What date picker you are using for and from your comment, date format should be same like your rule otherwise it will give you the format invalid error. According to you I tested your code it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ 'endDate', 'compareDate', 'compareAttribute' => 'startDate', 'operator' => '>=', 'type' => 'datetime', 'message' => 'Invalid Date' ],
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does?

Answer (score -1):

```
            [ 'endDate', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'startDate', 'operator' => '>=', 'type' => 'datetime', 'message' => 'endDate must be after staartDate' ],
```

this should work in Yii2. The rule compares the 2 Attributes as Dates.